# Access map value via index?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have this map:

```
m.insert(pair<int, string>(10, "map1"));
m.insert(pair<int, string>(11, "map2"));
m.insert(pair<int, string>(12, "map3"));
m.insert(pair<int, string>(13, "map4"));
m.insert(pair<int, string>(14, "map5"));
```

Then, I let user enter a number:

```
Please select:
1. Map1
2. Map2
3. Map3
4. Map4
5. Map5
```

Lets say, if user enters 3, how do I get the value: 12??

Comment: Did you get the requirement right ? I guess you  wanted the key by knowing the value.

Comment: If the integer in the pair is your value, then you have your key, value pair in the opposite order. It should be `pair<string, int>`. Then if the user selects `3`, then you can fetch it like: `m[string("map") + string(itoa(selection))]`.

Comment: I figured the routine to display the menu would iterate through the container, so the menu option really would be (one more than) the index. The answer then is to iterate the container to identify what the option was, just as was done to display it.

Answer (score 4):

`std::map` does not track the order in which its elements are inserted; the elements are stored in sorted order instead of insertion order.  If you need to keep track of the order in which elements were inserted, you need to do so yourself.  One way to do this would be to keep a second container that stores the keys in order, using a `std::vector`, for example:

```
std::vector<int> insertion_order;

m.insert(std::make_pair(10, "map1"));
insertion_order.push_back(10);
```

Then, the key of the `N`th inserted element is at index `N - 1` in the `insertion_order` sequence.

Comment: I dont get it. Like this: map<int, map<int, string>> ?? Is that what you mean?

Comment: My initial suggestion was less than ideal (to say the least).  Consider this new suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

With the current setup you have, there's no easy way to do this; you'd have to iterate over all the elements of the map looking for the one that had `Map3` as a value.

The `map` is optimized for looking up relationships in one direction.  Given a `map<K, V>`, you can easily map from `K`s to `V`s, but not the other way around.  The reason is that because you can store any `V` as a value, there's no guarantee that you'll get a unique inverse.  That is, given this map:

```
 0 -> 0
 1 -> 0 
 2 -> 1
```

There's no meaningful way to say which key has value 0; there are two such keys, 0 and 1.

You have many options here.  First, you could turn the `map` around and instead associate strings with integers, rather than integers with strings.  Based on your use case, this seems like what you wanted to do in the first place.  If you did that, then you could just use the square brackets operator to look up the associated value:

```
cout << m["Map3"] << endl;
```

Or, if you were concerned about what would happen with missing values, then you could write

```
map<string, int>::iterator itr = m.find("Map3");
if (itr != m.end()) {
    /* ... use itr to read the values ... */
}
```

Alternatively, if you really do have to have the map from integers to strings, and you know that each integer is paired with a unique string and vice-versa (that is, the map is a bijection), then you could use a [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) to encode this bidirectional relationship.  This would make it very easy to go back and forth between keys and values.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Map the integers in the menu to the data you wish to store. Consider:

```
struct data {
    data(int n, const std::string& s) : s(s), n(n) { }
    std::string s;
    int n;
};

// ...
std::map<int,data> m;
m.insert(make_pair(1, data(10, "Map1"));
m.insert(make_pair(2, data(11, "Map2"));
m.insert(make_pair(3, data(12, "Map3"));

int n = m[3].n;  // 12
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Compare: Comparison class: A class that takes two arguments of the key type and returns a bool. The expression `comp(a,b)`, where `comp` is an object of this comparison class and a and b are key values, shall return true if a is to be placed at an earlier position than b in a strict weak ordering operation. This can either be a class implementing a function call operator or a pointer to a function (see constructor for an example). **This defaults to `less<Key>`, which returns the same as applying the less-than operator `(a<b)`.
>   The map object uses this expression to determine the position of the elements in the container. All elements in a map container are ordered following this rule at all times.**

So the map class doesn't maintain the order of its elements as an array would.  If there were an indexing operator, it would like *not* return the i'th element added to the map.  It is an assocoiative collection, and you don't typically use that type of data structure when you need to maintain order by virtue of time of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

With newer versions of C++ (since C++17), we have the `std::advance()` function which can be used like so:

```
auto it = m.begin();
std::advance(it, index);
return it->first;   // or it->second depending on what you need
```

This is not a standard use case for an `std::map` so expect the `std::advance()` to become slower as the map grows larger and larger (i.e. complexity is linear or O(n) in this situation).